# Declare HTML tag as a string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, string-constant

I'm trying to assign the following HTML as a value to variable type string

```
    'here's the tag 
   '$("#close").click(function(){$.notifyBar({ html: "Click 'close' to hide notify bar", close: true, delay: 1000000 });});

        Dim htmltag = "$("#close").click(function(){$.notifyBar({ html: "Click 'close' to hide notify bar", close: true, delay: 1000000 });});"
```

I got a lot error message about the quotation in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use escape characters on the quotations otherwise they break the variable input.  The VB.net escape for quotations is double quote:

```
Dim htmltag = "$(""#close"").click(function(){$.notifyBar({ html: ""Click 'close' to hide notify bar"", close: true, delay: 1000000 });});"
```

In your example, the compiler would see the string as:

```
Dim htmltag = "$("
```

With lots of unknown stuff after it!

Other languages have different escape characters, javascript for example is backslash.